# Mongo: select only one field from the nested object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In mongo I store object that have field "titleComposite". This field contains array of title object, like this:

```
 "titleComposite": [
 "0": {
        "titleType": "01",
        "titleText": "Test cover uploading"
      }
 ]
```

I'm perfoming query and I would like to receive only "titleText" value for the returned values. Here is an example of my query:

```
   db.onix_feed.find({"addedBy":201, "mediaFileComposite":{$exists:false}}, {"isbn13":1,"titleComposite.titleText":1})
```

In the results I see values like

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("559ab286fa4634f309826385"), 
  "titleComposite" : [ { "titleText" : "The Nonprofit World" } ],          
  "isbn13" : "9781565495296" 
 }
```

Is there any way to get rid of "titleComposite" wrapper object and receive only titleText? For example, take titleText of the first element only?

Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 5):

You can mongodb [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) to achieve your expected result. Re-arrange your query as following...

```
db.onix_feed.aggregate([
               { 
                 $match: {
                      $and: [ 
                          {"addedBy":201}, 
                          {"mediaFileComposite":{$exists:false}}
                      ]
                 }
               },
               { 
                  $project : { titleText: "$titleComposite.titleText",
                               "isbn13" : 1 }
               }
])
```

Comment: thank you for answer. I tried your code, but I still see "titleComposite" in the resutls. { "_id" : ObjectId("559ab286fa4634f309826381"), "titleComposite" : { "titleText" : "The Geopolitics of Global Energy" }, "isbn13" : "9781626374331" }. I would like results look like { "_id" : ObjectId("559ab286fa4634f309826381"), "titleText" : "The Geopolitics of Global Energy", "isbn13" : "9781626374331" }

Comment: I have just edited my answer, please try the updated one

Comment: I still see "titleComposite" :/ I use Mongo 2.6.0 if it matters

Comment: I am sorry, Please retry my edited one... it will solve your problem

Comment: Yes, now "titleComposite" dissappeared. That's how result looks like: { "_id" : ObjectId("559ab286fa4634f309826385"), "isbn13" : "9781565495296", "titleText" : [ "The Nonprofit World" ] }. Is it possible to get rid of array and have string instead - just "titleText":"The Nonprofit World"?

Comment: What if i want to have all fields beside titleText ?